# How do I install a specific old version of MonoDevelop on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, mono, monodevelop

I am trying to install MonoDevelop version 5.4.1.7 so that I can use it with Mono 5.4.1.7.

First I tried installing Mono 5.4.1.7 by following the instructions here http://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/ except replacing `stable-bionic` with `stable-xenial/snapshots/5.4.1.7` (there are no 5.4 snapshots for Bionic). This worked:

```
$ sudo apt install mono-complete
[...]
mono-complete is already the newest version (5.4.1.7-0xamarin5+ubuntu1604b1).
```

Then I tried to do the same thing with MonoDevelop. I followed the instructions here http://www.monodevelop.com/download/ but I replaced `vs-bionic` with `vs-xenial/snapshots/5.4.1.7`. This didn't work:

```
$ sudo apt update
[...]
All packages are up to date.
W: Conflicting distribution: https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-xenial/snapshots/5.4.1.7 InRelease (expected stable-xenial/snapshots/5.4.1.7 but got xenial)

$ sudo apt install monodevelop
[...]
Package monodevelop is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'monodevelop' has no installation candidate
```

I also tried changing `stable-xenial` to `xenial`, and `sudo apt update` no longer throws an error but it still can't install MonoDevelop.

Why doesn't this work? How can I install MonoDevelop version 5.4.1.7 on my system?

Comment: Try replacing `vs-xenial/snapshots/5.4.1.7` with only `vs-xenial`, then `sudo apt update` again. What is the output of `apt-cache showpkg monodevelop` after doing that?

Comment: When I do that, it installs MonoDevelop `7.5.0.1254-0xamarin1+ubuntu1604b1` but it also adds Mono sources for 5.10, which I don't want. `apt upgrade` wants to change my Mono to `5.10.1.47-0xamarin4+ubuntu1604b1`. Also, this version of MonoDevelop does not launch with Mono 5.4 installed.